# pSortableColumn from primeng is not working

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I created a generic table component in angular and I'm trying to sort the columns with pSortableColumn but it's not working.

Follow code below:

```
  <p-table
    #dt
    [columns]="cols"
    [value]="lines"
    dataKey="id"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
      <div class="table-header">
        {{ tableName }}
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr class="white-space-nowrap">
        <th
          *ngFor="let col of columns"
          pSortableColumn="{{ col.field }}"
        >
          <div class="flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            {{ col.header }}
            <p-sortIcon field="{{ col.field }}"></p-sortIcon>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
      <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
          <span class="p-column-title">{{ col.field }}</span>
          <span>{{
            col.date
              ? (rowData[col.field] | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy')
              : rowData[col.field]
          }}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

I need to be able to sort all the columns, both in ascending and descending order.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How is it not working?  Are you getting any errors?  Is it sorting incorrectly or not sorting at all?

Comment: Also, instead of binding to `pSortableColumn="{{col.field}}"`, I would try the following syntax: `[pSortableColumn]="col.field"`

Comment: @JakeSmith not sorting at all. I've tried that way and it doesn't rank either.

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Is it possible that the `lines` variable contains immutable values?

Comment: @skink I don't get any errors and can't contain immutable values